# Are prepared statements disabled by default in MYSQLi? Like in PDO?

Tags: pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

In PDO the prepared statements are disabled by default.

And you need `$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` to enable them.

So i was wondering if it's the same in MYSQLi? Or are the prepared statements enabled by default in MYSQLi?

Answer (score 0):

> if it's the same in MYSQLi?

No.

Mysqli doesn't have emulation mode at all.

Comment: So does that mean that the prepared statements are always enabled? enabled by default in MYSQLi?